# device specific views in UWP

Tags: c#, windows, layout, win-universal-app

i know that i can make two different folders  : named  Device-family. Mobile and  Device-family Desktop and it works for me ... but know i need to different designs in the mobile device family itself : meaning i want to use deiffenrent backgrounds for 4" , 5" and 6" .... is that possible 
here is the code i used for the mobile  :

```
 <Grid Background="DarkMagenta">
    <TextBlock Text="mobile page " Margin="102,125,73,433" />
    <Button Content="mobile page" Margin="92,249,0,307" Height="84" Width="168"></Button>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it using AdaptiveTriggers please check  the documentation

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn890382

Comment: thanks ..i'm using visual state to modify my design according to each mobile phone .. so i have to
make 3 different designs for 4" , 5" et 6" ... but , whenever i try to modify the height of one list view
it changes in 3 of them ... so how can i set 3 different heights of my list view? 
PS : i think i can not use family device because it's made for tablets, desktops and mobile phones . Not the same family 
with different scale

Comment: please check the documentation of AdaptiveTriggers you can set the range of the width or height of this Triggers to be activated